# using exec to append data to file not in current directory

Tags: php, linux, centos, exec

i am trying to set up a little script to allow for php to append data to a file

the file is etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

i want to to automatically add data to the file for vhost use...

```
echo shell_exec('echo "hello" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf');
```

the code is not working, and not outputting anything

i have a feeling it is due to the working directory,

i am welcome to any other ways of doing this... but must be able to be called via a php window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's a permission problem. What are the permissions on your httpd.conf? You can check using `ls -l /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` if you're on Linux/Mac.

Comment: -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 34864 Apr 21 07:50 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Right, so if your httpd.conf is only editable by root then you're not going to be able to append to it as apache or whatever user your PHP is executing under. You'll either need to `sudo chown apache:apache httpd.conf` or else add apache to a group, make the file group writable `sudo chmod 664 httpd.conf` and then change the ownership to `sudo chown root:group_name httpd.conf`.

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much, new to the whole server stuff, so you was a big help!, thanks!